# how to bind combo-box in excel add in using office js

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

I want to bind combo box to excel cell and want to use auto fill feature of it using office javascript api in excel add in for office online.
Also please guid me for how to invoke developer options in excel and insert active x controllers of it and also acess its all properties.
[As per the Image above added the Combo Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30BNN.png)

Comment: Please add some detail and clarification to your question. In particular, it's not entirely clear what the "it" pronouns refer to. Also, note that Excel Add-ins that use the Office JavaScript APIs are cross-platform (work on Mac, iOS, Office Online, etc.) not just Windows, so they do not use Active X.

Comment: @RickKirkham thanks for suggestions my question is simple i want to add combo box in excel sheet how to do this ? using office online with javascript api "Office js". Is there any other way to achieve this.